# show and hide multible div's depend on 3 select boxes values

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dependencies

i have 3 selectlist with many options
i don't know any JS code
here is My HTML

```
<fieldset id="basic_data">
                <legend>Basic Data :</legend>
                    <h3 class="floatright">Type</h3>
                    <select class="" id="choosebuilding" name="choosebuilding">
                        <option value="flat">flat</option>
                        <option value="villa">villa</option>
                        <option value="3">commercial</option>
                        <option value="4">land</option>
                    </select>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    <h3 class="floatright">Payment</h3>
                    <select class="" id="choosecity" name="choosetype">
                        <option value="1">cash</option>
                        <option value="2">installement</option>
                        <option value="3">rent</option>
                        <option value="4">furnished</option>
                    </select>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    <h3 class="floatright">Choose City</h3>
                    <select class="" id="choosecity" name="choosecity">
                        <option value="1">Alrehab</option>
                        <option value="2">Settlement</option>
                        <option value="3">Madinty</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset><!-- end field set Basic Data -->
```

and i have many fieldsets that will show dependancy
like this

-- Address Data IF Alrehab + Madinty type flat --

-- Address Data IF Alrehab + Madinty type Villa --

-- Address Data All Commercial --

-- Address Data Settlement type flat OR And villa--

-- money cash Alrehab + Madinty --

-- money cash Settlement --

-- Credite Alrehab + Madinty --

-- Credite Settlement --

-- Rental All --

-- Furnnished All --

i believe i have many cases

i put all the necessary fields in my html and Commented it like so.

i want to show the used section of fields and hide other

Example of my hidden code

```
<fieldset id="furnished">
                    <legend>Furnished - All :</legend>
                        <h3 class="floatright">coast</h3>
                        <input name="rental_sum" class="input100" />

                        <h3 class="floatright">dialy</h3>
                        <input name="daily_rent" class="input100" />

                        <h3 class="floatright">insurance</h3>
                        <input name="insurance" class="input100" />

                        <h3 class="floatright">staff</h3>
                        <input name="annual_increas" class="input100" />

                        <h3 class="floatright">less</h3>
                        <input name="less_rent_time" class="input100" />

                        <h3 class="floatright">when ready</h3>
                        <input name="" class="input100" />

                    </fieldset><!-- end field set 11 -->
```

Comment: What's your question? "i want to show the used section of fields and hide other" makes no sense.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. I suggest you rewrite the question if you want a response. Also, why not try learning some javascript and having a go at solvin your problem yourself first. It's quite easy if you use jquery

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good place for jQuery show(), hide(), and some logic.

```
function updateShown(){
//First, hide everything that may have been previously shown.
  $("#furnished").hide();

//Next, start showing things based on user's selections
  //if ("Alrehab" or "Madinty") and ("flat" or "villa"), show addressData
  if ($("#choosecity").val() == 1 || $("#choosecity").val() == 3)
          && ($("#choosebuilding").val() == "flat" || $("#choosebuilding").val() == "villa") ){
      $("#addressData").show();
  }
}
```

Add `updateShown()` to the selects' `.change` event and you should be set.

Comment: i tried but it seems like i mess something .. i cannot figure what i will do with this code ?